# In unity3d deleted script in the editor now in visual studio I'm getting error that the script file could not be found. How can I fix the error?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
Source file 'I:\Unity Projects\Assets\My Scripts\Flocking\Flock.cs' could not be found.
```

I had the script in the editor I created the script. Then I deleted the script in the editor but now when I try to make in the visual studio: Build > Rebuild Solution I'm getting this error.

The script file is no longer in the editor and no longer on the hard disk.

Comment: Did you remove it from everything that could be referencing it? (Prefabs/Objects in your scene?)

Comment: The problem was not in the editor but in the visual studio in the Solution Explorer it seems that I had this script referenced in also another directory the script was deleted but the visual studio thought it's there but missing. Anyway deleted this directory from there too and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error is popping because you have deleted the file from your project, recycle the file from trash or recycle bin and try again...

Steps:
1. Goto Trash or Recycle bin
2. Find or locate Flocks.cs file
3. Right Click on file and click on Restore File
4. Goto Visual Studio and Rebuild the project

Comment: Yes, But I don't want to use this script that's why I deleted it. It was not accident. I just don't want the script at all.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi thanks for the clarification, happy coding